# Is the voltage of the dynamo coil spinning in magnetic field defined?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

A coil is spinning in static magnetic field as designed to generate electricity (a bicycle dynamo), with the constant angular speed $\omega$. If it is loaded by closing the coil circuit with some resistor $R$, the coil produces certain voltage and current. What is the voltage the coil produced when it is not loaded ($R$ infinite)? Is it theoretically infinite or some function of the coil parameters, rotating speed, magnetic field or something else?

I would assume the voltage generated by the coil should increase as we increase the value of the resistor $R$, but would it only be limited by the leak currents (we cannot really make $R$ to be infinity) or there is some lower limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Faraday's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html#c1) the voltage generated by a coil
in a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ is
$$V=-N\frac{\Delta(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{A})}{\Delta t}$$
where $N$ is number of turns and $\mathbf{A}$ is the area
enclosed by the coil.
For a dynamo (i.e. the coil rotating with angular speed $\omega$
in a static magnetic field) this simplifies to
$$V_\text{peak}=NBA\omega.$$

This voltage is the same whether there is a resistor $R$
connected to the coil or not.
The resistance $R$ just determines (by [Ohm's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmlaw.html#c1))
how much current will flow in reaction to this voltage.
So the current is
$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$

Comment: True ideally, but real generators have significant internal resistance. You must account for that in practice.

Comment: @JohnDoty In most cases the coil resistance can be modelled as a pure series resistance, which means the voltage loss follows from Ohm's law as well. For highly inductive coils that have a lot of parallel capacitance and are operating near resonance the actual impedances have to be determined. This is complicated by the fact that magnetic properties are non-linear near the load limit and so the system's behavior under load can also effectively (de)tune the resonance. I don't believe that practical generators are operating in that regime but I am not a power AC engineer, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yep. In real physics, one strategy is to start with a model that's wrong and keep adding epicycles until it's adequate. Not quite as bad as Ptolemy, though, as we do have theory to help decide what epicycles to add. The procedure is, however, not perfectly reliable.

Comment: @JohnDoty Exactly. I would keep it simple for the understanding of the physics of it. Anybody who likes to do finite element simulations on rotating magnetic structures can join the EE department or the R&D departments of companies that manufacture electric generators and motors. That is certainly a viable career path for some.

Comment: @FlatterMann Philip Sadler's famous social experiment shows how badly our idealized textbook physics is equipping students to understand the physics of ordinary things.

Comment: @JohnDoty I wouldn't call FEM software "physics". At best it's applied math to solve an engineering problem. It doesn't ask "How does nature work?". It tries to give us quick approximate solutions to things that were know about nature in the late 19th century, already. Having said that, I agree that many EM textbooks are teaching very bad habits about approximation procedures by employing systems of infinite size (planes, wires etc.). If I could make one change to EM textbooks it would be the introduction of rational approximation methods. I am not a theorist, so that's not my work, though.

Comment: @FlatterMann Who's talking about FEM? I'm talking about simple circuits. When MIT students, who all had to pass freshman physics at least, can't conceptualize what a circuit is, we have a problem.

Comment: @JohnDoty "Circuit theory" was a three semester series of courses at my university that all EE students had to take.  One of them told me that he just couldn't stand it any more having to calculate yet another four-pole circuit transformation. Just because physicists know Maxwell doesn't mean they (have to) know how to do proper EE. That's a different art altogether, but it is an art (or science, if you want). I have also met very smart theorists whom I admire who didn't know what the inductor in a fly-back circuit did. That's OK. They didn't have to. That was my job. Divide and conquer.

Comment: @FlatterMann Sure. But I'm not talking *sophisticated* circuit theory: I'm talking about the kind of thing I learned when I was nine years old building a model railroad. As Sadler showed, many students are *never* exposed to this elementary, everyday, useful physics.

Comment: @JohnDoty Nothing stops a physics student from learning EE. There are plenty good textbooks on the matter. But truthfully... why does everybody have to be a EE these days? Or a CS? I have actually taught CS to first semester computer scientists as a teaching assistant to make some money. Of course the basics are not that hard in anything. That doesn't mean I can do more than the basics in either EE or CS, though. I can only do enough to get my own job as an experimentalist done. That's all I ever needed. Could I publish a non-trivial EE or CS paper? No. I also don't have to.

Comment: @FlatterMann I'm not talking about learning to be an EE. I'm talking about elementary real world physics. I'm talking about students who, despite having been taught physics at a world leading university, can't make a light bulb light up.